# ¿Cómo almacenar un resultado en un dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemáticas

Realizo un cálculo de diferencia en dos columnas de marco de datos que se encuentra en una tercera columna. Sin embargo, si se realiza el cálculo, este último no se almacena en el dataframe.

```
def predictions(train):

    print("cosine_sim")
    train["cosine_sim"] = train.apply(cosine_sim, axis = 1)
    print("diff")

    i = 0
    for index, row in train.iterrows():
        i += 1
        row["diff"] = row["quest_emb"] - row["sent_emb"]
        if i % 10000 == 0:
            print("row ",i)
            print("row[\"diff\"] ",row["diff"])        
    print("euclidean_dis")
    print(train)
```

Entonces el primero `print("row[\"diff\"] ",row["diff"])` en el `row i` me da :

```
row  10000
row["diff"]  [[-0.00541345 -0.00239381  0.00431296 ... -0.01337912 -0.0073709
   0.        ]]
row  20000
row["diff"]  [[-0.03855522 -0.00136002 -0.02514186 ... -0.06655771 -0.02910786
  -0.02423212]
 [-0.03762216 -0.031567   -0.01083523 ... -0.01431298 -0.03401132
  -0.01916602]]
```

Pero la columna resultante se llena con `NaN` :

```
                                                sent_emb  \
0      [[0.030376578, 0.044331014, 0.081356354, 0.062...   
1      [[0.030376578, 0.044331014, 0.081356354, 0.062...   
2      [[0.030376578, 0.044331014, 0.081356354, 0.062...   
3      [[0.030376578, 0.044331014, 0.081356354, 0.062...   
...  
16289  [[0.035860058, 0.049851194, 0.0662197, 0.02581...   

                                               quest_emb  \
0      [[0.01491953, 0.021973763, 0.021364095, 0.0393...   
1      [[0.04444952, 0.028005758, 0.030357722, 0.0375...   
2      [[0.03949683, 0.04509903, 0.018089347, 0.07667...   
3      [[0.03284301, 0.01849968, 0.020346267, 0.03835...   
...  
16289  [[0.03924892, 0.04188699, 0.025356837, 0.04136...   

                                              cosine_sim  diff  
0      [0.1401391625404358, 0.11776834726333618, 0.09...   NaN  
1      [0.12254136800765991, 0.08665323257446289, 0.0...   NaN  
2      [0.09432470798492432, 0.06841456890106201, 0.0...   NaN  
3      [0.1274968981742859, 0.09279131889343262, 0.08...   NaN  
...
16289  [0.060139477252960205, 0.07225644588470459, 0....   NaN
```

También probé fuera de una función, pero ni siquiera crea la columna.

Answer (score 0):

que tal si creas una lista afuera del loop y luego la agregas al DF

```
def predictions(train):
    tmp = []
    ...
    for index, row in train.iterrows():
        tmp.append(row["quest_emb"] - row["sent_emb"])

    train['diff'] = tmp
```